# ezPublish does not generate CSS cache (php 5.4 incompatibility?)

Tags: php, caching, ezpublish

We have a site which runs on a Debian Squeeze (PHP 5.3.3) host and should be duplicated on Debian Wheezy (PHP 5.4.4).

On the new installation, we face the problem, that the stylesheet cache is not generated.
i.e. the folder `/var/www/example.com/web/var/example_website/cache/public/stylesheets` is not created. When we fully delete this cache folder, the structure is created, but no stylesheets.

Is there a general compatibility problem with PHP 5.4?

How can this be debugged?

Comment: debian wheezy comes with php 5.4 - debian lenny was before squeeze

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eZ Publish is compatible with php 5.4 from version 2012.1 upwards.

see:
http://share.ez.no/forums/install-configuration/php-5.4.1-no-call-method-defined-for-function/%28language%29/eng-GB